# Apache 2.4 Stops Serving Request

Tags: apache-2.4

This is something new, Apache is running fine as server on a Windows Server 2012. There is plenty of RAM and CPU and this is the only thing this server does, is an Apache server.

I can restart the service and it will run fine for a little bit then stop serving pages on all sites. I have messed with the worker threads to find a fine line but still having issues.

Currently settings in httpd-mpm.conf file

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             10
    MinSpareServers          10
    MaxSpareServers         20
    MaxRequestWorkers      250
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   3000
</IfModule>
```

At this point I am not sure what is going on and have tried several suggestions from various websites.

Specs of Server:
Windows 2012 R2 VM
2 GB of RAM 1 GB available
Running on an SSD storage

This server connects to a MySQL database on the same network as well, there is not latency between the servers.

Comment: Any errors in apache log? Stop serving meaning what, timeout, connection refused, http error?

Comment: That's another odd thing, that was the first thing I looked for was max connections or something but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I don't know what is going on, woke this morning and it has been working fine.

Comment: Nope, I was wrong, it started acting up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at your MaxRequestWorkers setting. Depending on your average memory usage, which will be fairly substantial if using anything (i.e. php) other than static content, the number may be high for 2G RAM.

Look at your average Apache process size to get usage x MB. Consider how much memory you want to keep available for other processes y MB and use this formula for prefork.

```
 (Total RAM – yMB)/xMB = MaxRequestWorkers
```

Also, why have you raised the MinSpareServers? As noted in the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html#minspareservers),

> Tuning of this parameter should only be necessary on very busy sites. Setting this parameter to a large number is almost always a bad idea.

If the site is so busy that it must be raised, this also calls into question the sufficiency of 2G RAM. The same might be said of [StartServers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#startservers), which in fact could be lowered to 2 even on a server with only 2G RAM.

For additional reference, you can look at the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html#hardware) for performance tuning this issue.

Comment: I have adjusted the settings based on the documentation and it still stops. It comes back but it seems that it is random. This is not a busy site, it is just a Wordpress site that gets less than 100 hits a day. I've had this site running on less resources before.

Comment: what is your average apache process size? and how many files are downloaded on a typical page of the site?

Comment: I am collect more data around this but from what I have witnessed, it ranges from 25MB - 60MB.

Comment: these are typical for php based processes (e.g. Wordpress). what about the number of files (css, images, icons, html, etc) per typical "hit" on the site? also, how much RAM do you estimate needs to be reserved for MySQL? when you "reset" the config, what did you set for the MaxRequestWorkers?

Comment: Right now I only have one site online and I have no idea the number of files, best guess, 20-30. Database is on a different server so this is not a factor. I've set the maxrequestworkers to many numbers, high and low, currently set at 250.

Comment: Well, that is probably the problem. Taking 2 GB minus 750 MB for Apache itself, anything else and a bit of reserve and then dividing by 50 MB estimated average Apache process gives you a MaxRequestWorkers value of 25. Assuming that the number of files in a single hit is only 20, you will be swapping to disk if you have just two simultaneous visitors and you have set the MaxRequestWorkers to any value above 25. Once the disk swapping starts, the "crash" will follow.

Comment: What would your recommendation be with the settings. Also, this VM is on an SSD disk.

Comment: This problem is well documented all over the Internet. Here is one [example](http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/3-small-tweaks-make-apache-fly) that explains rather eloquently: "[s]et it too high and watch your server die in a slow, painful death as Apache runs out of RAM and starts swapping to disk. And watch page response times go from milliseconds to seconds or even minutes."

Comment: Set it to 25, and then monitor. You may have to lower, but you might also be able to nudge it up. Depends on how reacts real world.

Comment: The SSD is a good thing, but this problem looks like a RAM thing

Comment: I had this running in a Ubuntu box before I switched to  Windows with less resources, why so many problems now.

Comment: Maybe you are getting more simultaneous traffic. I don't really know. I do know that if you try to have Apache handle more that it has memory for, as opposed to orderly queuing traffic, you will kill Apache. The default install in Ubunto is also event (or maybe worker), by the way, which is more memory friendly